# mysql: unknown variable 'innodb_lock_wait_timeout=500'

Tags: mysql

I have a query, that takes time to execute, because I'm importing the geonames table

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'allCountries.txt'
INTO TABLE geoname
CHARACTER SET 'UTF8'
(geonameid, name, asciiname, alternatenames, latitude, longitude, fclass, fcode, country, cc2, admin1, admin2, admin3, admin4, population, elevation, gtopo30, timezone, moddate);
```

However, if I execute the query, I always get

```
Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction
vagrant@homestead:~/work/homestead/project/bin$
```

So I tried to increase the lock time out. The documentation states here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_lock_wait_timeout that the CLI-parameter is `--innodb_lock_wait_timeout=#`, but when I set it in my query

```
mysql -ugeonames -psecret --local-infile=1 --innodb_lock_wait_timeout=500 geonames < geonames_import_data.sql
```

I'm getting the error

```
mysql: unknown variable 'innodb_lock_wait_timeout=500'
```

But my MySQL version `mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.6.19, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper` should support this setting, right?

When I set it globally like `SET GLOBAL innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 500;` and then read the value with `show variables like '%lock_wait%';` I'm getting the correct values

```
+--------------------------+----------+
| Variable_name            | Value    |
+--------------------------+----------+
| innodb_lock_wait_timeout | 500      |
| lock_wait_timeout        | 31536000 |
+--------------------------+----------+
```

How do I use it on the command line though?

My Versions:

```
select @@version // 5.6.19-0ubuntu0.14.04.1
mysql --version // mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.6.19, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper
```

Comment: Which one (client and server) if using either versions 5.0 and 5.6?

Comment: No idea, but it's mostly the same for 5.6 http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_lock_wait_timeout

Comment: And in your script you can't use "SET SESSION innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 500 ;" ?

Comment: Hey, when I set it globally or in a script it works perfectly. I was just wondering why it doesn't work on the CLI

Comment: Alright, to see versions you run `mysql --version` (client) and `select @@version` (server).

Comment: local-infile is not taking any value... can you try it like --local-infile

Comment: Hey. Nope, the same error appears

Answer (score 1):

You probably have an older version of mysql or at least the cli is old, probably from the v5.0 series. If you check out the documentation you linked yourself, then you can see the following at [innodb_lock_wait_timeout description](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_lock_wait_timeout):

> Name  :innodb_lock_wait_timeout
>
> Variable Scope:   Global
>
> Dynamic Variable: **No**

The dynamic variable no means that the variable cannot be set on the fly, only in the my.ini and the value will only change if the server is restarted. You will get the error message you described if you try to change the variable dynamically.

Comment: Hey, I have v 5.6 - I simply linked to the wrong documentation. 5.6 states that it is a dynamic variable. and mysql -v shows me 5.6 as well

Comment: This is why I wrote "older version of mysql or at least the cli is old".